# Integrate Twitter search API in Cocoa

Tags: ios, cocoa, twitter, hashtag

I want to get tweets with a specific hashtag. I use the Twitter search URL. This is my code:

```
  NSMutableString *urlString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%s","http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23zesdaagsegent"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSLog(@"%@", data);
    NSError *error;
    NSMutableArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@", json);

    NSMutableArray *results =[NSMutableArray array];
    for(NSDictionary *item in json)
    {
        [results addObject:[item objectForKey:@"results"]];
    }
```

My NSLog gets me the output I need:

> 2013-05-28 09:48:45.080 ZesdaagseGent[572:11303] {
>       "completed_in" = "0.023";
>       "max_id" = 339031661368975360;
>       "max_id_str" = 339031661368975360;
>       page = 1;
>       query = "%23zesdaagsegent";
>       "refresh_url" = "?since_id=339031661368975360&q=%23zesdaagsegent";
>       results =     (
>                   {
>               "created_at" = "Mon, 27 May 2013 14:53:41 +0000";
>               "from_user" = SigfridMaenhout;
>               "from_user_id" = 369194526;
>               "from_user_id_str" = 369194526;
>               "from_user_name" = "Sigfrid Maenhout";
>               geo = "";
>               id = 339031661368975360;
>               "id_str" = 339031661368975360;
>               "iso_language_code" = nl;
>               metadata =             {
>                   "result_type" = recent;
>               };
>               source = "<a href="http://twitter.com/">web</a&gt;";
>               text = "#zesdaagsegent Het is een zonnige dag hier in Merelbeke. We verlangen allemaal naar een beetje zonnestralen in het
>   gezicht, toch?";
>           }
>       );
>       "results_per_page" = 15;
>       "since_id" = 0;
>       "since_id_str" = 0; }

I need the array "results" with the objects in. My problem is that I can't get the results in an NSMutableArray with the method objectForKey.

Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: do you want to add record into dictionary or array.

Comment: I want to get the array of results, for the moment there is only 1 tweet, but there will be more tweets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];
NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data 
                                                             options:kNilOptions 
                                                               error:&error];
for (NSDictionary *result in jsonResponse[@"results"]) {
    [results addObject:result];
}
```

And you should have a NSArray `results` containing X NSDictionary for each of the matching tweets.

PS : [@"results"] is the modern Objective-C syntax for [NSDictionary objectForKey:@"results"]